# React Native: Open SMS / Mail Inside App Rather than Opening iMessage/Mail

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I currently have it set up and working like below, however it switches out of my app and into the actual iMessage / Mail apps for my links.

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconContainer} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(`mailto:${email}`)}>
  <Feather name="mail" size={20} color="black" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I've seen it done in other apps where the mail/iMessage screen is stacked on top within the app, rather than exiting the app and opening iMessage/mail.

I can't seem to figure out how to get it done this way, would really appreciate the help!

Note: I'm using Expo, not bare React Native.

Comment: You will need to use some library that uses `MFMessageComposeViewController` and `MFMailComposeViewController`

Comment: Any updates on this? I also want iMessage to be like a modal and not take me to a new app.